# How can I get a basic notification with Noty plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, noty

I am trying to use [Noty plugin](https://github.com/needim/noty) to create notification in my application.

Unfortunately the documentation are more complected that I can understand. so I am failing to generate a simple alert that appears on the upper right hand of the screen.

Here is what I have done.

First, I included the following two files

```
noty/js/noty/jquery-noty.js
noty/js/noty/layouts/topRight.js
```

I added default configuration like this

```
$(function(){

    $.noty.defaults = {
        layout: 'topRight',
        theme: 'defaultTheme',
        type: 'alert',
        text: '',
        dismissQueue: true, // If you want to use queue feature set this true
        template: '',
        animation: {
            open: { height: 'toggle' },
            close: { height: 'toggle' },
            easing: 'swing',
            speed: 500 // opening & closing animation speed
        },
        timeout: true, // delay for closing event. Set false for sticky notifications
        force: false, // adds notification to the beginning of queue when set to true
        modal: false,
        maxVisible: 5, // you can set max visible notification for dismissQueue true option
        closeWith: ['click'], // ['click', 'button', 'hover']
        callback: {
            onShow: function () { },
            afterShow: function () { },
            onClose: function () { },
            afterClose: function () { }
        },
        buttons: false // an array of buttons
    };

});
```

Then I Added a click event to trigger the notification like this

```
$(function(){

    $('#test').click(function(){
            noty({
                text: 'Simple Test!'
            });
    });
});
```

When I click the test button I get nothing on the screen and no errors in the console.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I create a simple notification that appears on the upper right hand side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `template` setting in `$.noty.defaults` is blank.  Try supplying one:

```
template: '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span><div class="noty_close"></div></div>',
```

Comment: That worked with no style. but since it is this difficult to create a basic notification I decided to not use noty, I ended up using https://notifyjs.com/